# How to add breakpoint when thread sanitizer reports data-race?

Tags: gcc, gdb, thread-sanitizer

There is a similar question for address sanitizers, but for thread sanitizers, it doesn't work, I have tried to break on __sanitizer_print_stack_trace, which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Run the program under GDB, set breakpoints on `exit` and `_exit`. On Linux, also set `catch syscall exit_group`.
2. set `halt_on_error=1` in `TSAN_OPTIONS` to ask thread sanitizer to [exit on first error](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerFlags):

```
(gdb) set env TSAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=1
(gdb) run
... error should be reported and one of the breakpoints should fire.
```

3. Profit.

P.S. When the breakpoint is hit, use GDB `where` command to see how the error is reported. Setting a breakpoint on some kind of `__tsan_report_error` that is likely on the stack will probably work even without setting `halt_on_error`.

Comment: I also had to add `abort_on_error=1` to `TSAN_OPTIONS` to make gdb break instead of exit (see https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/SanitizerCommonFlags)

Answer (score 4):

The first time I enabled Thread Sanitizer on my project, Xcode helpfully added a breakpoint for me in the Breakpoint Navigator. But I deleted it when I was done testing. Now I need it again and Xcode didn't create it for me when I enabled Thread Sanitizer again.

Note that I am using Xcode 11.0 here.

To manually re-create this breakpoint, you need to have the Breakpoint Navigator open. Then click the plus button (**+**) at the bottom-left of the navigator and select **Runtime Issue Breakpoint** from the pop-up menu. This adds the breakpoint to the navigator, and a window appears.

[image: thread sanitizer breakpoint]

From the **Type** drop-down list, select **Thread Sanitizer**.

There you go! Silly that this option is buried way down there. But I also found it helpful to note that there are more options for different kinds of breakpoints available from that plus button menu than there are from the main Xcode drop-down menu **Debug > Breakpoints**.